# It shows error when build iOS App using Jenkins. The Apple Developer account can not be logged in

Tags: ios, jenkins

The error message is:

```
Code Signing Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to log in with account '****@*******'. The login details for account 'surez@planetart.cn' were rejected.

Code Signing Error: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't support the Associated Domains, iCloud, and Push Notifications capability.

Code Signing Error: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't support the iCloud.com.planetart.fpnl iCloud Container.
Code Signing Error: Provisioning profile "iOS Team Provisioning Profile: *" doesn't include the aps-environment,
com.apple.developer.associated-domains,
com.apple.developer.icloud-container-identifiers,
com.apple.developer.icloud-services,
and com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers entitlements.

Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 12.1'
```

Has anybody encountered such error before? We saw it many times and spend a lot of time to deal with this error. Thanks for any hint.

Comment: Did you enable the Associated Domains, iCloud, and Push Notifications, from app target  Capabilities

Comment: Yes. We enable associated domains iClouds and Push Notifications in Xcode Capabilities.